# Equivalent form of vectorization of Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, kronecker-product, vectorization

This question is hard to ask, but I'll try to be as specific as I can.

For matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$, is there an equivalent representation (see below) for the vectorization of the Kronecker product of $A$ and $B$, i.e. $\text{Vec}(A \otimes B)$?

When I say an "equivalent representation", I am specifically asking for a quantity which is equal to $\text{Vec}(A \otimes B)$ where the $\text{Vec}$ operator only appears through $\text{Vec}(A)$ or $\text{Vec}(B)$

For example, if I were asking for an "equivalent representation" for $\text{Vec}(AB)$ (now assuming $n=p$), one could answer $(I \otimes A)\text{Vec}(B)$ or $(B^{T} \otimes I)\text{Vec}(A)$.

I hope the question is clear enough. I have tried to have a look around, and even show something, but I could not.

edit: One can write $\text{Vec}(A)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{e}_i \otimes (A\mathbf{e}_i)$ and so $\text{Vec}(A \otimes B)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{nq}\mathbf{e}_i \otimes ((A \otimes B)\mathbf{e}_i)$, which I guess works. Is there a nicer form for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Result:** $\operatorname{vec}(A \otimes B) = [I_m \otimes K^{(q,m)} \otimes I_q][\operatorname{vec}(A)\otimes \operatorname{vec}(B)]$, where $I_k$ denotes the identity matrix of size $k$ and $K^{(q,m)}$ denotes a [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix).

*Proof:* It suffices to consider the case that $A = uv^T$ and $B = xy^T$ (for column vectors $u,v,x,y$). We have
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A \otimes B) = \operatorname{vec}[(uv^T) \otimes (xy^T)] = 
\operatorname{vec}[(u \otimes x)(v \otimes y)^T]
 = v \otimes y \otimes u \otimes x.
$$
It now suffices to use the fact that $K^{(q,m)}(u \otimes y) = y \otimes u$ to show that the matrix $P = I_m \otimes K^{(q,m)} \otimes I_q$ satisfies
$$
P(\operatorname{vec}(A) \otimes \operatorname{vec}(B)) = 
P(v \otimes u \otimes y \otimes x)=
v \otimes y \otimes u \otimes x =  \operatorname{vec}(A \otimes B).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Ben Grossmann's answer is incorrect.

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$.
$$vec ( A \otimes B ) = \left(\mathbb{I}_n \otimes \mathbb{K}_{(q, m)} \otimes \mathbb{I}_p \right) \left(  vec(A) \otimes vec(B) \right)$$
not
$$vec( A \otimes B ) = \left(\mathbb{I}_m \otimes \mathbb{K}_{(p, n)} \otimes \mathbb{I}_q \right) \left(  vec(A) \otimes vec(B) \right)$$

**Proof** (see [Matrix differential calculus with applications to simple, hadamard, and kronecker products. Jan R. Magnus, H. Neudecker](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022249685900069))

Let $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^m \ (i=1, \dots, n)$ and $b_j \in \mathbb{R}^p \ (j=1, \dots, q)$ denote the columns of $A$ and $B$, respectively.
Also, let  $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n \ (i=1, \dots, n)$ and $u_j \in \mathbb{R}^q \ (j=1, \dots, q)$ denote the columns of $\mathbb{I}_n$ and $\mathbb{I}_q$, respectively.
Then we can write $A$ and $B$ as $A = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i^T$ and $B= \sum_{j=1}^q b_j u_j^T$.
So
$$
vec ( A \otimes B )
= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^q vec \left( ( a_i e_i^T) \otimes (b_j u_j^T) \right) \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^q vec \left( (a_i \otimes b_j) (e_i \otimes u_j)^T \right) \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^q (e_i \otimes u_j) \otimes (a_i \otimes b_j) \\
= \left(\mathbb{I}_n \otimes \mathbb{K}_{(q, m)} \otimes \mathbb{I}_p \right) \left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n vec (a_i e_i^T) \right) \otimes \left( \sum_{j=1}^q vec(b_j u_j^T) \right) \right] \\
= \left(\mathbb{I}_n \otimes \mathbb{K}_{(q, m)} \otimes \mathbb{I}_p \right) \left(  vec(A) \otimes vec(B) \right)
$$

**Example** : For $(m, n, p, q) = (2, 3, 2, 2)$ take
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 & 3\\ 4 & 7 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 7 \\ 6 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then
$$A \otimes B =\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 14 &  8 & 28 &  6 & 21 \\
12 &  6 & 24 & 12 & 18 &  9 \\
8 & 28 & 14 & 49 &  4 & 14 \\
24 & 12 & 42 & 21 & 12 &  6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So
$$vec ( A \otimes B ) =\begin{pmatrix}4 & 12 &  8 & 24 & 14 &  6 & 28 & 12 &  8 & 24 & 14 & 42 & 28 & 12 & 49 & 21 &  6 & 18 & 4 & 12 & 21 &  9 & 14 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$\left(\mathbb{I}_n \otimes \mathbb{K}_{(q, m)} \otimes \mathbb{I}_p \right) \left(  vec(A) \otimes vec(B) \right)=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 12 &  8 & 24 & 14 &  6 & 28 & 12 &  8 & 24 & 14 & 42 & 28 & 12 & 49 & 21 &  6 & 18 & 4 & 12 & 21 &  9 & 14 &  6 \end{pmatrix} = vec ( A \otimes B )$$
But
$$\left(\mathbb{I}_m \otimes \mathbb{K}_{(p, n)} \otimes \mathbb{I}_q \right) \left(  vec(A) \otimes vec(B) \right)=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 12 &  8 & 24 &  8 & 24 & 14 &  6 & 28 & 12 & 28 & 12 & 14 & 42 &  6 & 18 &  4 & 12 & 49 & 21 & 21 &  9 & 14 &  6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I happened to notice your post; thanks for the correction, I've corrected my answer accordingly. By the way, it looks like you're missing vec operators in the second to last line of your proof.

Comment: Thanks @BenGrossmann. I've inserted it.