# Solving Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, products, kronecker-product

I am trying to solve for X the following: $XA + B(X \otimes Y)Q=C$  is there a closed form solution to this? Thank you in advance.
Note: How I can derive $B(X \otimes Y)Q$ with respect to X and then find the closed form of  $XA + \frac{dX}{d B(X\otimes Y)Q} B(X\otimes Y)Q=C$

Note: This problem  is part of optimization problem-solving iteratively the proposed equation is the result of the derivation of the previous problem, What I need now is to isolate the variable X to be as X =... in term of other matrices to be used to update the X variable

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Unfortunately, your post doesn’t fully meet this site’s policy (see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)). I recommend that you edit your post. (1) You should provide some context to your question. Where is this problem from? Why is it interesting and important? (2) Please tell in the post, did you try to solve it? What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?

Comment: If $X$ is $m\times n$ and $Y$ is $p\times q$. Using [this vectorisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4765525) of $\operatorname{vec}(X\otimes Y)$, the equation can be rewritten as $M\operatorname{vec}(X)=\operatorname{vec}(C)$, where
\begin{align*}
M=\left[
(A^T\otimes I_m)+
(Q^T\otimes B)
\big(I_n\otimes K^{(q,m)}\otimes I_p\big)
\big(I_{mn}\otimes\operatorname{vec}(Y)\big)
\right]
\end{align*}
and the dimensions of the four Kronecker products are $mr\times mn,\ mr\times mnpq,\ mnpq\times mnpq$ and $mnpq\times mn$ respectively. ...

Comment: ...As in any system of linear equations, solutions may not exist or be unique. The smallest-norm least-squares solution is given by $\operatorname{vec}(X)=M^+\operatorname{vec}(C)$.

Comment: Thank you so much